# Why do we initialize top of the stack as -1?

Tags: c

Why do I have to initialize one of the stacks to -1? Where would top1 point to?

```
int ar[SIZE];
int top1 = -1;
int top2 = SIZE;

void push_stack1 (int data)
{
  if (top1 < top2 - 1)
  {
    ar[++top1] = data;
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("Stack Full! Cannot Push\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: this is `C`, why have you added `python` tag?

Comment: C arrays are indexed from `0` so the first time you push an item with `ar[++top1] = data;` the index is incremented from `-1` to `0` before use.

Comment: It's the index for stack underflow.

Comment: "*Where would top1 point to?*" nowhere, as it isn't a pointer.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri my apologies. I was asking python questions earlier and i must have mistakenly tagged it as python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is whether you let `top1` point to the last used element or the first free element.

With `-1` you let it point to the last used element.

With `0` you let it point to the first free element.

There is also symmetry in the use of pre-increment/decrement and post-increment/decrement.

Initializing to `-1` implies `++top1` for push and `top1--` for pop.

Initializing to `0` implies `top1++` for push and `--top1` for pop.

Comment: I think this is the only answer that really addresses what OP is asking

Comment: Thank you. This reminds me of i++ and ++i in C... I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

No, you wouldn't have to initialize `top1` as `-1` at all if your code would have been:

```
int ar[SIZE];
int top1 = 0;   // 0 `here`
int top2 = SIZE;

void push_stack1 (int data)
{
  //        v  conditional check with `<=` instead of `<`
  if (top1 <= top2 - 1)  // even better: `if (top1 < top2)`
  {
    ar[top1++] = data;
    //    ^  using "top1++" instead of "++top1"
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("Stack Full! Cannot Push\n");
  }
}
```

`++something` *(also known as pre-increment)* will increment the value of `something`, and then return the incremented value.

Whereas, `something++` *(also known as post-increment)* will increment the value of `something`, but return the original value that `something` held before being incremented.

But you must note here that whether it is `++top1` or `top1++`, we are always passing `0` as the first index to `ar` because the `0` is the first index of any array/list in all the languages.

Comment: As a consequence of your change, you now must compare `<=` otherwise the last element is not used.

Comment: Nitpicking: `top1 <= top2 - 1` is just an ugly way to write `top1 < top2` ;)

Comment: @zvone thanks! added it in comment though, in order to make it explicit regarding the nature of change as OP seems to be *newbie* :)

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is really odd that you started to think that in stack datastructure's implementation - you would have to initialize top with `-1`. Whick book said that? If any book did, at it's best it can mostly mean *that the implementation they showed is following that*.

Where would `top1` point to? If you directly index into an array object, then yes it would likely try to access a memory which is out of the array bound, which is surely an undefined behavior(Arrays are `0`-indexed in C ). But in *every* scenarios, we see implementation where `top` is increased first (in case `top` is initialized with `-1`)`++top` and then that value is used to index into array (For the very first time this will result in `0`), which is precisely the case here. (Array is mentioned here because it seems that underlying data structure the code you showed uses that).

So `top=-1` will initially mean that it is in a empty state and you can say no member is being added to the stack data structure. Here you could have initialized `top` with `0` also *provided that* you would have to change your `push`,`pop` or `isEmpty()` and other auxiliary functions associated with this data structure implementation accordingly, as needed.

Also you can check your other function's implementation to get the justification of `top=-1` for the implementation with which you are working on.

---

Also if you are in doubt about what `++` does here and how is it significant - Look what C11 standard has to say about it (N1570Draft)

In section  §[6.5.3.1¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.1p2)

> The value of the operand of the prefix `++` operator is incremented. The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.

`++top1` will result in the new incremented value which is `0` in case it was `-1` earlier.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation.