# Implement a stack using the first element of an array as top

Tags: c, stack

I am implementing a stack in C. The task i have been given requires me to use the first element of the array as top. 
For example:
If i have the `struct`:

```
struct stack {
    int arr[MAX];
    int top
};
```

I need to assign the first element of arr(i.e. `arr[0]`) to top and then implement the stack.

I don't get the question as top is usually assigned the value `-1` and is accordingly incremented or decremented. What exactly do I need to do here?

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you didn't paraphrase requirements. Also, show some effort yourself, like e.g. formatting code for easier reading and detailing what you have done so far. Nobody here is going to do your homework for you, even though people are willing to help you!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am new to this website. Please help me in any way possible .

Comment: I just did. I told you how to improve your question.

Comment: "usually" the initialization of stack top depends on its meaning: does it point to the first free element or the last used element? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474020/why-do-we-initialize-top-of-the-stack-as-1/48474237#48474237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather strange requirement, because the most natural way to implement the stack is using the **last** element of the array as the top by adding new elements at the end of the array and removing them from the end.

This way you will satisfy the LIFO requirement of the stack and also avoid moving the rest of the data in the array as you would have if you were adding and removing elements from the beginning of the array.

Also I'm not sure what is the **top** member of your struct is supposed to do, but the most natural thing to have here is some way to indicate what is the last element of the array currently is (i.e. the top of the stack). So it seems to me that the **top** member should contain the **index** of the last element in the array and by doing `stack.arr[stack.top]` you will retrieve the top element of the stack.

Comment: First or last element doesn't matter; you'll just have to let your algorithm calculate the other way around.

Comment: See also my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474020/why-do-we-initialize-top-of-the-stack-as-1/48474237#48474237 about the meaning (and initialization) of the stack top.